# Composer instance freeze, metadata.google.internal authentication error

Tags: google-cloud-composer

Our Composer instance dropped all its active workers in the middle of the day. Node memory and cpu utilization disappeared for 2 out of 3 nodes.

First errors were:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'airflow-sqlproxy-service.default.svc.cluster.local' (110))"
```

Restarting Composer instance (with a dummy env variable) does not help, gives the below error:

[image]

Killing GKE workers in error does not help either. Stackdriver has this:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.describe) You do not currently have an active account selected.)
```

And another error seems to point to internal Google authentication service problem:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: Unable to find the server at metadata.google.internal)
```

The Composer storage bucket seems to have 'Storage Legacy Bucket ...' permissions for some service accounts. Some changes going on in the authentication backend or what could be the underlying cause of the sudden and weird freeze?

Versions are composer-1.8.2 and airflow-1.10.3.

Comment: Which version of composer are you running? Also, can you check the if your service account still have the required roles?

Comment: Image is composer-1.8.2-airflow-1.10.3.
Service account should have the required roles, although many of them though the 'Storage Legacy Bucket ...' permissions for the Storage bucket the composer is using. Added extra permissions, Storage Admin, for the service account for the bucket, but didnt help. 
We ended up spawning a new Composer instance. Works, but ofc we lost the Airflow database, so the task run histories and run times are gone.

Comment: Can you upgrade your environment to the newest version of Composer? The current one is : *composer-1.10.3-airflow-1.10.2*. You can do it using the comand `gcloud beta composer environments update ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
    --location LOCATION --image-version VERSION` or the console, you should follow the steps described [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading#gcloud_1). According to the [release notes] (20th of March) there were improvements made in the SQL stability connection within workers. Please, let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Tried the update from the console a couple of times, but it ended up, after an hour or so of running the update, in authentication error. Giving the particular service account Storage Admin permissions to the Composer storage bucket did not help. Would the gcloud CLI command have worked better?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using the correct service account with the appropriate permissions in your Composer environment, [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#access-control)?